# Is my Angular Material MessageBox component well build?

Tags: angular-2+

My angular knowledge is limited, so I don't know much yet about it's garbage collection etc to make sure my component can be used without any strange side effects or memory leaks.

I've created a stackblitz with a working version of the component here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-messagebox?file=src/app/app.component.ts

So I have a button that will trigger the 'message box dialog' like this:

```js
  openMessageBox(buttons: Buttons) {
    // mb is injected in constructor
    let dialog = this.mb.show('Title','Message',buttons);

    dialog.dialogResult$.subscribe(result=>{
      console.log("Button pressed: ", Button[result])
    });
  }
```

After clicking one of the buttons available the dialog will close and will inform what button was pressed.

My dialog provider looks like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MessageBox {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  private dialogResultSubject!: Subject<Button>;
  dialogResult$!: Observable<Button>;

  show(message: string, title?: string, buttons?: Buttons): MessageBox {

    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MessageBoxDialog, {
        data: {
          message,
          title,
          buttons: buttons ?? Buttons.Ok
        }
      }
    );

    this.dialogResultSubject = new Subject<Button>();
    this.dialogResult$ = this.dialogResultSubject.asObservable()

    dialogRef.componentInstance.dialogResult$.subscribe(pressedButton => {
      this.dialogResultSubject.next(pressedButton);
      this.dialogResultSubject.complete();
      dialogRef.close();
    });

    return this;
  }
}
```

I complete the subject in the provider because the `mb` instance (of provider) is not destroyed.

The `MessageBoxDialog` is a simple Component that displays the Title and a Message along with the chosen buttons:

```js
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Buttons, Button } from "../common";
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  templateUrl: './message-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-box.component.scss']
})
export class MessageBoxDialog {

  title = '';
  message = '';
  buttons: Buttons = Buttons.Ok;

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {
    this.title = data.title;
    this.message = data.message
    this.buttons = data.buttons;
  }

  dialogResultSubject = new Subject<Button>();
  dialogResult$ = this.dialogResultSubject.asObservable();

  public get Buttons(): typeof Buttons {
    return Buttons;
  }

  public get Button(): typeof Button {
    return Button;
  }

  click(button: Button) {
    this.dialogResultSubject.next(button);
  }
}
```

```
<h2 class="mat-dialog-title">{{title}}</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>{{ message }}</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions *ngIf="buttons === Buttons.Ok">
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="click(Button.Ok)">Ok</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
<mat-dialog-actions *ngIf="buttons === Buttons.YesNo ">
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="click(Button.Yes)" tabindex="-1">Yes</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="click(Button.No)" class="mat-primary">No</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

I hope to receive feedback about whether I created this all in a good way (or not) and some tips to improve.